# preg_replace PHP to replaceall JAVA

Tags: java, php, preg-replace, replaceall

Can anyone help me converting this code in java?

```
$linkc= strtolower(preg_replace(array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-éèàê€-]/', '/(-){2,9}/'), '_', $jour['nom']));
$linkc = preg_replace('/€/', '_', $linkc);
$link .= preg_replace('/[èéêëàáâãåäæìíîïòóôõöøùúûü]/', '', $linkc);
$nom = $jour['nom'];
```

I'm really new to regular expression,first of all, I don't really understand `array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-éèàê€-]/', '/(-){2,9}/')` what this pattern means, then , I tried myself with

```
String nom = rubrique.getNom();
nom = nom.replaceAll("[èéêëàáâãåäæìíîïòóôõöøùúûü]", "");
nom = nom.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-éèàê€-]", "_");
nom = nom.replaceAll("(-){2,9}", "_");
```

which doesn't remove the accent letters....

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The expression

`array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-éèàê€-]/', '/(-){2,9}/')`

means:

"one of the regex in the array must fit". These regex are:

`'/[^a-zA-Z0-9-éèàê€-]/'` - **just one** character which is not a-z and not A-Z and not 0-9 and not é etc. Probably not what you want?

`'/(-){2,9}/'` - just at least 2 up to max 9 "-" - probably also not what you want.

In order to substitue all accent chars by "-":

```
 ... '/[éèàê€]+/', '-' ....
```

Have a look at [this](http://regexpal.com/) as well, you might test regex against input "on the fly"

Furthermore: `preg_replace` might have arbitrary results on multibyte chars. You probably have a look at [mb_ereg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) which is capable to handle multibyte chars like é in the expression etc.

Comment: In fact, I need to convert this in Java, get any idea?